# Dynamic content updates not appearing on site

Tags: web8.5, dynamic-publishing, cache

We are using web8.5 (none of DXA or DD4T) and consuming content delivery API in a web app with ActiveMQ\JMS cache enabled. We are hosting multiple sites in the same presentation server and one of the sites the dynamic content isn't getting updated on publishing. Only after an app pool recycle the changes are getting reflected. I have checked config values in the site's storage config and they are the same for all the sites and also I am confused about how to debug it as I don't see any error logs on the microservices side or presentation side.

I would appreciate any help on how to debug it.

Comment: Welcome to Tridion stack exchange. Can you make sure if the dynamic content is indeed updated on the broker DB . If so when you say you have multiple sites running on same presentation And using activeMQ Can you make sure the topics are unique and also make sure the cache invalidation is happening properly when you publish the content at the deployer . Provide more details on how many services are running on the presentation server and how the active MQ is configured .

Comment: Is that web app uses CIL rest API or in-process API?

Comment: @Velmurugan Web app is using in-process API

Comment: I would suggest using the Webapp to CIL.

Comment: @Guest123 can you update the post if the dynamic content updates worked based on the suggestion.